# How to deal with pypi requirements.txt that are specific to dev environments?

Tags: setuptools, pypi, requirements.txt

I have this kind of conundrum regarding how to deal with `requirements.txt`: my package has a list of 4-6 requirements needed to install and use the package, still in order to run the unittests and to develop you have a much bigger set.

If I put all of them inside the requirements.txt, I will increase the chance of people not being able to install the package due to broken dependencies.

Also some of these dependencies are more like optional, installing them would be desired but missing them should not prevent installing the whole package.

Now, I created a `requirements-dev.txt` file where I put the development ones, but this approach is not friendly with PyCharm or even setuptools because they do not know to recognise this filename so they will not install the requirements unless I am manually doing it.

How should we solve this?